# XSLT Stylesheet loop

Tags: xml, xslt

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<xsl:for-each select="JournalData/PatientData/CasebookMemo">

<tr bgcolor="#FBF5A4">
<th>CasebookMemo</th> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="ID" /></td>
</tr>


</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:for-each select="JournalData/PatientData/CasebookMemo/CreatedBy">

<tr bgcolor="#FBF5A4">
<th>CreatedBy</th> 
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="*">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>


</tr>


</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I'm getting....

**CasebookMemo**
CasebookMemo
**CasebookMemo**
CasebookMemo
**CasebookMemo**
CasebookMemo
**CasebookMemo**
CasebookMemo
**CasebookMemo**
CasebookMemo
**CreatedBy**
CreatedBy
**CreatedBy**
CreatedBy
**CreatedBy**
CreatedBy
**CreatedBy**
CreatedBy
**CreatedBy**
CreatedBy
**CreatedBy**
CreatedBy

....but what I need is a loop that looks like this:

**CasebookMemo**
CasebookMemo
**CreatedBy**
CreatedBy
**CasebookMemo**
CasebookMemo
**CreatedBy**
CreatedBy
**CasebookMemo**
CasebookMemo
**CreatedBy**
CreatedBy

and so on....since I'm looping through an XML where CasebookMemo is followed by CreatedBy, then a new instance of CasebookMemo and CreatedBy....and so on...

Many thanks in advance for any help:)

### /Paul

Thanks for your help! I made it passed this problem just to run into another one.

This is my current stylesheet:

```
<xsl:for-each select="JournalData/PatientData/CasebookMemo/ID">
<tr bgcolor="#FBF5A4">
<th>CasebookMemo</th> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="../CreatedBy">
<tr bgcolor="#FBF5A4">
<th>CreatedBy</th> 
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="*">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:for-each select="../../OwnedBy">   
<tr bgcolor="#FBF5A4">
<th>OwnedBy</th> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

....and this is the outcome:

[image]

What happened to all elements under "OwnedBy" (actually same as under CreatedBy)? Why aren't they visible? After every "CreatedBy"-section, there should be an "OwnedBy"-section.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please show us an example of the input and post your expected result **as code**. I am guessing you want the second xsl;for-each to read `<xsl:for-each select="CreatedBy">` - but that's only a (wild) guess at this point.

Comment: It's been a while since I used XSLT but I suspect you need to move the `CreatedBy` template *into* the `CasebookMemo` for-each loop. That way, each time a `CasebookMemo` is found and processed, the `CreatedBy` element(s) will get processed before moving onto the next `CasebookMemo`.

Answer (score -1):

I made 3 changes to make it work:

1. `<xsl:for-each select="../../OwnedBy">` was changed to `<xsl:for-each select="../OwnedBy">`
2. After `<tr bgcolor="#FBF5A4">` `<th>OwnedBy</th>` `</tr>`
   a line was added: `<xsl:for-each select="*">`
3. That statement was closed by a `</xsl:for-each>`

Comment: This doesn't help anyone.

Comment: Well, perhaps not, though I'm not that good in explaining how these things work....but I will try. Regarding the three changes above; The first was obviously a faulty relative link so the element was never found. The second points to that a loop through all sub-elements was necessary. The third simply closes the second one.